# How to install complete, easily updatable LaTeX system with text editor front-end?

Tags: software-recommendation, xubuntu, latex

I'm new to Xubuntu, having used Windows XP for many years.  On Windows I ran MiKTeX, with editors/front-ends WinEdt and TeXworks.  I found the MiKTeX Package Manager and Update tools to be especially useful.

I'm now running Xubuntu 12.04 LTS.  How should I install a complete, easily updatable LaTeX system with text editor/front end?

Comment: Texworks is available for Linux too, so if you are comfortable with it, simply install it. You then have tens of dedicated editors if you want, from gedit to vim with latex-suite to like. Add texlive-full and you will have the full TeX ecosystem on your disk, or one of the base packages if you want to save space.

Answer (score 2):

You can try `sudo apt-get install texlive`. The updated packages are usually available in the distribution repo, current version is 2013. However, there are other packages (other than the default install set) that you might need to install depending on the latex package you want to use in your document. You can use Synaptic to search for and install necessary packages.

As for editors, you are spoilt for choice. You can use emacs, kile, etc. You can also use eclipse with texlipse. Even gedit comes with a latex plugin.

There are a couple of other ways to install latex support on your system, which are more involved. You can manually download desired (or missing) packages from CTAN, place them in `$HOME/texmf/tex/latex/`. Place the desired package directory there (the directory is expected to contain the `.sty` file, and other optional documentation or source files). Then, execute `sudo texhash`.

Or you could download the latest TexLive distribution from the project page, and install  using tlmgr.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to have a look at [Eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/) (I use Juno) with the [texlipse](http://texlipse.sourceforge.net/) add-on.

It will work and look the same in Windows and Linux. This is independent from your package manager. For that I would follow the [latex-project](http://latex-project.org/ftp.html) recommendation.